# Foreign Key column on subgrid invalidates template

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Kendo grid that is my main grid:

```
@using Resources;
@using ITSV6.ElysiumDataService;
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI.Html;
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Resource.PayRules;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var Holidays = (IEnumerable<att_holidays>)ViewData["Holidays"];

    var PayCodes = (IEnumerable<att_pay_codes>)ViewData["PayCodes"];
}

<div class="row">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<att_pay_rules>()
                    .Name("GridPayRuleDefinition")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.pr_pay_rule).Hidden();
                        columns.Bound(p => p.pr_name).Title(Resource.Name).Width("").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").ShowOperators(false)).Extra(false));
                        columns.Bound(p => p.att_fixed_rules.fr_name).Title(Resource.FixedRule).Width("").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").ShowOperators(false)).Multi(true));
                        columns.ForeignKey(m => m.tr_terminal_rule, (IEnumerable<att_terminal_rules>)ViewData["Terminals"], "tr_terminal_rule", "tr_name")
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
                           .Title(@Resource.TerminalRule);
                        columns.ForeignKey(m => m.wr_work_rule, (IEnumerable<att_work_rules>)ViewData["WorkRules"], "wr_work_rule", "wr_name")
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
                           .Title(@Resource.WorkRule);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.pr_laborday_hours)
                        .Format("{0:n2}")
                        .Title(Resource.LaborDayHours)
                        .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:right;" }).HtmlAttributes(new { align = "right" })
                        .Width("").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").ShowOperators(false)).Multi(true));
                        columns.Command(command =>
                        {
                            command.Custom("Copy").Text(" ").SendDataKeys(true).Click("copyGridRecord").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "fa fa-files-o fa-lg", title = Resource.Duplicate + " " + Resource.PayRule });
                            command.Edit().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { title = Resource.Edit + " " + Resource.PayRule });
                            command.Destroy().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { title = Resource.Delete + " " + Resource.PayRule });
                        }).Width(140);
                    })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text(Resource.AddNewPayRule))
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Text(" " + Resource.Print + " " + Resource.Report).HtmlAttributes(new { target = "_blank", @class = "iconPrint" }).Action("GenerateAndView", "Reports", new { subDir = "", reportName = "SetupPayRulesSummary" }))
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Excel().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "iconExcel" }))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("payRuleDefinition").Window(w =>
            {
                w.Width(485);
                w.Title(Resource.PayRule + " " + Resource.Editor);
            }
                ))
            .Excel(excel => excel.FileName("PayRules.xlsx").ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Pay Rules")).Filterable(true).AllPages(true))
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .Editable(e => e.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
            .Scrollable(a => a.Height("100%"))
            .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("subgrid")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)

                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(pk => pk.pr_pay_rule);
                    model.Field(f => f.att_fixed_rules).DefaultValue(new att_fixed_rules());
                    model.Field(f => f.att_terminal_rules).DefaultValue(new att_terminal_rules());
                    model.Field(f => f.att_work_rules).DefaultValue(new att_work_rules());

                })
                .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "PayRuleDefinition"))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "PayRuleDefinition"))
                .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "PayRuleDefinition").Data("ConvertDates"))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "PayRuleDefinition"))
                .Events(ev => ev.Error("handleGridPayRuleDefinition")
                   .RequestEnd("GridPayRuleDefinition_onRequestEnd")
                )
            )
            .Events(e =>
            {
                e.Remove("function(args){gridRecord_Remove(args,'GridPayRuleDefinition');}");

            })
)
</div>
```

And the result looks like this - link added, I don't have enough "reputation points" to attach the image, sorry ):
[Main-Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxrpZ.png)

This grid has records with information. Each record on the left has a "+" button that should display a subgrid with `Holiday` records that can be edited in InLine mode. And the code of the subgrid looks like this one:

```
<script id="subgrid" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<att_pay_rules_holidays>()
        .Name("grid_#=pr_pay_rule#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.pr_pay_rule).Hidden();
            columns.ForeignKey(m => m.hdy_holiday, (IEnumerable<att_holidays>)ViewData["Holidays"], "hdy_holiday", "hdy_name")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
                    .Title(@Resource.Holiday).Width("30%");
            columns.ForeignKey(m => m.pc_pay_code, (IEnumerable<att_pay_codes>)ViewData["PayCodes"], "pc_pay_code", "pc_name")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })
                    .Title(@Resource.PayCodes).Width("30%");
            columns.Bound(c => c.prh_time_payed).Title(Resource.Hours).Width("20%");
            columns.Command(cmd =>
            {
                cmd.Edit().Text(" ").CancelText(" ").UpdateText(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { title = Resource.Edit + " " + Resource.LaborAccount + " " + Resource.Entry });
                cmd.Destroy().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { title = Resource.Delete + " " + Resource.LaborAccount + " " + Resource.Entry });
            }).Width("15%");
        })
       .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text(" " + Resource.Add + " " + Resource.New + " " + Resource.Holiday).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "iconAdd" }))
       .Editable(e => e.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
       .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
       .Events(ev => ev.Remove("function(args){ gridRecord_Remove(args,'grid_#=pr_pay_rule#');}"))
       .Pageable()
       .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
       .Sortable()
       .DataSource(ds => ds
               .Ajax()
               .Model(model =>
               {
                   model.Id(p => p.pr_pay_rule);
               })
               .Read(read => read.Action("ReadHoliday", "PayRuleDefinition").Data("getRulesHolidaysData(#=pr_pay_rule#)"))
               .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateHoliday", "PayRuleDefinition"))
               .Create(update => update.Action("CreateHoliday", "PayRuleDefinition").Data("function(args){AssignPayRule(args,#=pr_pay_rule#)}"))
               .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DestroyHoliday", "PayRuleDefinition"))
               .Events(ev => ev.Error("function(args){handleGridError(args, 'grid_#=pr_pay_rule#')}"))
       )
       .Events(e =>
       {
           e.Remove("function(args){gridRecord_Remove(args,'grid_#=pr_pay_rule#');}");
       })
       .ToClientTemplate()
)
</script>
```

And the result looks like this:
[Sub-Grid displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsBgp.png)

And the subgrid should contain records that have information about `Holidays`. As you see, the foreign keys columns are filled like this:

```
columns.ForeignKey(m => m.hdy_holiday, (IEnumerable<att_holidays>)ViewData["Holidays"], "hdy_holiday", "hdy_name")
```

And the problem is when I click the "+" button in any of those records in the main grid, the subgrid gets invalidated and I guess is due to the foreign key columns. If I open the Google Chrome console when I try to display a `Holiday` record, it gets "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error. Each foreign key column on the subgrid should generate a DropDownList with `Holiday` and `PayCode` options when a `Holiday` record is being edited or when a new `Holiday` record is being created. But that is not what is happening.

Any suggestions?

**[EDIT 1]**

*If I change the mode from InLine to PopUp and I expand the columns, then the problem is gone. But, unfortunately, this is not allowed. The records must be edited in InLine mode.*

Comment: Anyone who can help me on this? I found something similar on Telerik's forums, [that states when a DropDownList is created by a ForeignKey column, the template goes invalid](https://www.telerik.com/forums/'-'-in-drop-down-list-data-can-invalidate-generated-kendo-template) and I think that is what it is happening to me, but I can't find any solution at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue where I wanted inline editing but also with a hierarchical grid.  Here is a link to their code sample that inspired me to take a certain direction.
One of the keys to making this all work is ensuring that any "dropdown" types of inline editing you need are defined in your Shared Views.

https://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/grid-ajax-hierarchy-editing

Comment: OH, YEAH SIR. You saved my life. That was the main cause of this. I have added the GridForeignKey.cshtml file into my Shared/EditorTemplates folder and it worked like a charm. My god, I passed almost 5 days wasting my time searching for a solution because of this. Problem solved, thank you. I will edit the title. Oh, and I'm sorry :( I can't upvote your comment. I don't have enough reputation points to do it, but I really appreciate your help :)